# Other Near Inverses in Mathematics

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, soft-question

As a young mathematician, one learns that the derivative and integral are kind of like inverse operations, but not quite. The two fundamental theorems of calculus require some additional assumptions to go through. Moreover, the maps $f \mapsto f'$ and $f \mapsto F$ (where $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$ for some fixed $a$) both fail to be injective and surjective on many function spaces. Yet, it remains a useful intuition to think of integration and differentiation as opposite, if not inverse, operations.

Are there other examples of this near inverse behavior in mathematics? Is there a more general phenomenon like this that integration and differentiation are just examples of?

Comment: Differentiation is a left-inverse of integration, meaning that $(D\circ I)(f)=f$ for every  continuous function $f$. Left and right inverses appear in many contexts. In general a function needs to be injective in order to admit a left-inverse and surjective to admit a right-inverse (what are the domain and codomain of the maps $D, I$?). As another example from linear algebra (where domain and comdomain are more mundane objets), $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is a left-inverse of $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.